# Banco de dados SQLite e Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Olá, estou fazendo um pequeno app e preciso buscar dados do banco de dados e exibir eles na tela.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String BANCO_DADOS = "Nomes";
    private static int VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BANCO_DADOS, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE nomes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "nome TEXT, data_nascimento DATE);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

NomesActivity.class

```
public class NomesActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    private DatabaseHelper helper;
    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tarefas_activity);

        String[] de = {"nome" ,"dataNascimento"};
        int[] para = {R.id.nome, R.id.dataNascimento};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listarNomes(), R.layout.nomes_list_activity, de, para);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> nomes;

    private List<Map<String, Object>> listarNomes() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, nomes, data_nascimento FROM nomes", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        nomes = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

            Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            String id = cursor.getString(0);
            String nome = cursor.getString(1);
            long dataNascimento = cursor.getLong(2);

            item.put("id", id);

            item.put("nome", nome);

            Date dataNascimentoDate = new Date(dataNascimento);
            String exibirData = "Nasceu em " + simpleDateFormat.format(dataNascimentoDate);
            item.put("dataNascimento", exibirData);

            nomes.add(item);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return nomes;
    }
}
```

O que acontece é que, quando entro na Activity, aparece esse erro:

> Unfortunately, Nomes has stopped

Eu já olhei os logs e não me aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro. Como resolver?

Comment: Nada no `logcat`? Só pelo código eu observei que você tenta utilizar o `helper` em `listarNomes()` antes de iniciá-lo. Coloque a linha que você faz a inicialização antes do *SimpleAdapter*. Fora isso, precisaríamos de mais detalhes do erro.

Comment: Aparece que tem erros em: `String exibirData = "Nasceu em " + simpleDateFormat.format(dataNascimentoDate);` e em `SimpleAdapter adapter`